# Convert Blob to DataURL in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, blob, data-uri, data-url

I have a `blob` variable which represents an audio file. When this code is executed, a valid data url string is logged into console, but it is very small and works only in chrome, the browser probably stores it somewhere. Is it possible to convert it into a data url string that contains all the audio data? Also, everything works properly on other machines.

```
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
     reader.onloadend = function() {
                    base64data = reader.result;                
                    console.log( base64data );
      }
```

Thanks.

Comment: The data url represents the whole data of a file. Are you sure your blob is not a stream? Also, FileReader is [pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader)

Comment: @Kaiido, Firstly, no, it does not represent the whole data in my case, in my case it is very small, and if i open it in another browser, it doesn't work. Secondly, I am sure my blob is not a stream, because when I open the data url in chrome, it works fine. Thirdly, FileReader is supported in my browser.

Comment: Ah you were talking about the dataURL which doesn't work in other browsers... My bad. But still, the support was point 3 of my comment.  Can you check point 2 or show us how you created this blob, since obviously the problem comes from that.

Comment: The Blob works, because if I open the data url in chrome, the audio plays perfectly.

Comment: No if your blob contains a stream, then the blobUrl you open from your browser will display the media, which is being updated constantly. But your blob only contains the actual data at currentTime, not a whole file.

Comment: @Kaiido , Is there a way I can check if it is a stream or not?

Comment: Yes check your code. Or show it to us, we may be able to tell you, but to convince yourself that the problem is not in the fileReader, you can simply check the `blob.size`

Comment: 1720364 for an 8-second audio. Is it still a stream?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88763/discussion-between-kaiido-and-vlas).